# Adding modal form to my custom Joomla 3 component

Tags: php, joomla, modal-dialog

I have read several tutorials on how to create a modal popup in Joomla. All of them describe the two main requirements on the side of creating a link that opens a modal dialog.

e.g. import the JHTML behavior.modal javascript, and then add a class of "modal" to the link that opens it.

That works fine. My link opens a modal dialog. The problem is that I can't seem to find anything that describes what needs to be done to the actual form (view, template, etc.) so that it will display in that modal dialog. Right now my modal dialog is just a small white square. No content. My link which opens it looks like this:

```
<a class="modal" href="index.php?option=com_openice&view=rinkdashboard&layout=form&tmpl=component">open form</a>
```

I have a file called form.php inside the /tmpl/ directory for that view. The contents of form.php are as follows:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<h2>Add/Edit Ice Time</h2>
```

At this point I'm just trying to get it to display before I add anything to it. If I go directly to the URL in the link I can view this page. But I get nothing when it is opened in a modal dialog.

Is there something that needs to be added to the target view/layout for it to work as modal? (I've looked at other forms which are opened modally and can't identify a pattern).

Thanks for any help,
Clay

Comment: If the site is white try to set the error reporting value to maximum in your Joomla configuration. Perhaps you get a fatal error.

Comment: I have my error reporting set to maximum and still there are no errors on the modal dialog. The background page which launches the modal has no errors, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason of your problem must be  **'Not defining of the width and height of the popup'.**

So please modify your code to something like this and your component will be displayed in the modal pop:

```
<a class="modal" href="index.php?option=com_openice&view=rinkdashboard&layout=form&tmpl=component" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 600, y: 450}}">open form</a>
```

Accept this answer if it works for you or else further explain your problem so that we can help you.

Comment: It worked! So odd that most articles about this don't show examples of the rel attribute as being mandatory. They all include examples without it at all. Anyway, good catch.